# Not understanding why raycast code isnt working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Here is the Code:

```cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RaycastControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    LineRenderer line;
    private Vector3 zeros;
    public LayerMask EnemyLayer;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        zeros = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Detected the click");
            Vector3 mouse = mouseToWorld(Input.mousePosition);
            Ray ray = new Ray(zeros, mouse);
            RaycastHit hitData;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, 10000, EnemyLayer))
            {
                Vector3[] linePos = new Vector3[] { transform.position, mouse };
                line.SetPositions(linePos);

                Debug.Log("You've hit a Zomboid!");
            }
        }
    }
    public Vector3 mouseToWorld(Vector3 mousePos)
    {
        mousePos = Input.mousePosition;
        mousePos.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane;
        Vector3 mouse = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(mousePos);
        mouse.z = 0f;

        return mouse;
    }
}
```

Note: I'm using Unity2d
I'm trying to use 0,0,0 and the location of my mouse to cast a ray starting from 0,0,0 and running through the mouse location on to the specified max distance in if(physics.Raycast(ray,maxDistance,EnemyLayer)).  this, however, does not work.  When I click on or behind the "Zombie" object I've created, I dont get a raycast hit detected.

[image: What the scene view looks like]

I've been sure to make sure that the layer mask set in this script is the same one set in the Zombie object.  My Debug.Log("You've made it this far!"); line activates so I know the Script is in the scene and is being read, but the Physics.Raycast(ray,10000,EnemyLayer)) NEVER returns true, and we know this because Debug.Log("You've hit a Zomboid!") never shows up in console.

Note: The object this script is attached to, Center, sits at 0,0,0.  its transform.position = 0,0,0

Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Are you trying to hit a Collider2D? In that case you would rather need to use `Physics2D.Raycast` !

Comment: In addition to the above remember that `Physics/2D.Raycast` accepts a `LayerMask` to selectively **ignore** layers. If all bits in the layerMask are on, it will collide against all colliders. If the layerMask = 0,  it will never find any collisions with the ray.

Comment: @derHugo is right.  I should have been using Physics.2D for the 2d box collider.  I did not realize that it could not work with 2d box colliders.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Physics` and `Physics2D` are separate in Unity and don't interact with each other.

`Physics2D.Raycast()` belongs to Physics2D and only responds to Physics2D (BoxCollider2D, CircleCollider2D, PolygonCollider2D, etc.)

`Physics.Raycast()` belongs to Physics and only responds to Physics (BoxCollider, SphereCollider, MeshCollider, etc.)

You are using `Physics.Raycast()` when you should be using `Physics2D.Raycast()`.

This is how you would do it:

````cs
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class RaycastControl : MonoBehaviour
{
    LineRenderer line;
    //private Vector3 zeros;
    public LayerMask EnemyLayer;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        line = GetComponent<LineRenderer>();
        //zeros = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f); not necessary this is the same as Vector3.zero
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1"))
        {
            Debug.Log("Detected the click");
            RaycastHit2D hit = Physics2D.Raycast(Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition), Vector2.zero);
            if (hit)
            {
                Vector3[] linePos = new Vector3[] { transform.position, hit.point};
                line.SetPositions(linePos);

                Debug.Log("You've hit a Zomboid!");
            }
        }
    }
}```
````